# Image picker is not retrieving the image?

Tags: flutter

I am using the package Image_picker. The objective is to attach an image in the screen from the Library.
I got to access to the image library, but for some reason is not retrieving the image in the screen after selecting it.

This is the code:

```
  File image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            AppBarTransparentComponent(centerTitle: true, title: 'New Message', showBack: true, backgroundColor: TheBaseColors.lightBlue),
          ];
        },
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _subjectController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _bodyController,
                    maxLines: null,
                    expands: true,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Body', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: image != null
                                  ? ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                child: Image.file(
                                  image,
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                ),
                              )
                                  : Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.camera_alt,
                                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () =>
                              { imgFromGallery()
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text('Attach files'),
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      imgFromGallery();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () => {},
                              color: TheBaseColors.lightGreen,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Text('Send'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future imgFromGallery() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 25, maxWidth: 1920, maxHeight: 1080);

    setState(() {
      image = image;
    });
  }

}
```

How can I make the image selected visible in the screen? I am setting up the state with the selected image and then returning it in a container. What am I missing?

Comment: In your `imgFromGallery` method you are declaring a var named `image` as well and you are re-assigning it to itself in the `setState`. You would want to change the name to "pickedImage" or something :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  File image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            AppBarTransparentComponent(centerTitle: true, title: 'New Message', showBack: true, backgroundColor: TheBaseColors.lightBlue),
          ];
        },
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _subjectController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _bodyController,
                    maxLines: null,
                    expands: true,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Body', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: image != null
                                  ? ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                child: Image.file(
                                  image,
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                ),
                              )
                                  : Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.camera_alt,
                                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () =>
                              { imgFromGallery()
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text('Attach files'),
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      imgFromGallery();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () => {},
                              color: TheBaseColors.lightGreen,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Text('Send'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future imgFromGallery() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 25, maxWidth: 1920, maxHeight: 1080);

    setState(() {
      this.image = image;
    });
  }

}
```